# Excel VBA - Find and copy non-matching rows to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to compare 2 columns in the same worksheet, search for non-matching values in column A when compared to column D and copy the entire rows of these non-matching values in column A to another worksheet.

Here is a sample of the worksheet:

[image]

Therefore, I would like to compare column A with column D, find the values which do not match and copy the entire corresponding rows from Columns A and B to a new worksheet.

*Edit, I forgot to include my code

```
Dim CopyToRow As Integer
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim found As Range

'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
CopyToRow = 2

Set rng1 = Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown))
Set rng2 = Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 2), ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 2).End(xlDown))

For Each cell In rng1

Set found = rng2.Find(what:=cell, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

If Not found Is Nothing Then

cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & CopyToRow)

CopyToRow = CopyToRow + 1

End If

Next cell
```

Many thanks and much appreciated!

Comment: This is not supposed to be a free code-writing service, so please show what you have tried, and explain where you have run into problems.  Also, give your Excel version and why you need to do this using VBA.  You could do this using the Advanced Filter, merge the tables, and retain only the distinct rows.

Comment: My apologies, I neglected to add my code detailing the issue. Nonetheless, I appreciate the feedback!

Comment: I think it would be simplest to use Power Query, and do a `LeftAnti` type of join, using both columns as the `key`. That would retain those rows in table 1 that are not present in table 2, and you would output the results to a fresh workbook.

Comment: Thank you for your update! I had not thought to consider Power Query to perform LeftAnti type of join. Where can I locate more resources going into detail for this?

Comment: You can do an internet search with terms like `Power Query` and/or `Power BI`.  There are numerous groups, blogs, tutorials, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Ron Rosenfeld that you should have demonstrated your own attempt.  That being said, perhaps this will be of some help to you. Not the most elegant but should work provided you update references to your own sheet names.

```
Sub SOPractice()
    
    Dim SearchCell As Range 'each value being checked
    Dim SearchRng As Range 'column A
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim MatchFound As Range
    Dim i As Long: i = 1
    
    LastRow = YourSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    With YourSheet
        Set SearchRng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 1))
    
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each SearchCell In SearchRng
        Set MatchFound = .Range("D:D").Find _
        (What:=SearchCell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
        
        If MatchFound Is Nothing Then 'No match hence copy to other sheet
            .Range(SearchCell.Address, SearchCell.Offset(, 1)).Copy
            YourCopyToSheet.Cells(i, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            i = i + 1
        End If
    
    Next SearchCell
    
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Noted and thank you for helping me with the solution nonetheless! It worked as I intended!

Answer (score 0):

I have also found a solution, using a Dictionary object:

```
Dim Cl As Range, Rng As Range, Dic As Object

Set Dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

With Dic
For Each Cl In MyWorksheet1Name.Range("D2", MyWorksheet1Name.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    .Item(Cl.Value) = Empty
Next Cl
For Each Cl In MyWorksheet1Name.Range("A2", MyWorksheet1Name.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    If Not .Exists(Cl.Value) Then
    If Rng Is Nothing Then Set Rng = Cl Else Set Rng = Union(Rng, Cl)
    End If
Next Cl
End With

If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    Rng.EntireRow.Copy MyWorksheet2Name.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
End If
```

Cheers!